# Prevent/hide error alert bar in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am constantly getting this error on my visual studio code. Although I know why its coming, but unfortunately, I can not fix this issue.

**What I want now to hide this alert coming again and again or may be to hide this alert appear specifically for this error only.**

[image]